# Odoo 9 qweb report style modification

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am trying to modify my qweb report contents in Oddo 9 like table position, fonts, heights, shipping address position should come on top right side etc. by using css. But  any of my changes are not reflecting in pdf report. Please suggest me the correct way to do it.

Here below is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <openerp>
    <data>
       <template id="report.style" name="style">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            color: #000 !important;
            }
            .table table-condensed {
            border-top: 1px solid black !important;
            }

         </style>
      </template>  


      <template id="report_custom">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                        <div class="page">
                               <div class="oe_structure"/>

                                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th class="text-right">Quantity</th>
                                                <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
                                                <th t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">Disc.(%)</th>
                                                <th class="text-right">Taxes</th>
                                                <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                                            </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody class="sale_tbody">
                                            <t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="l">
                                                <tr t-if="l.product_uom_qty">
                                                    <td>
                                                       <span t-field="l.name"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="text-right">
                                                        <span t-field="l.product_uom_qty"/>
                                                        <span groups="product.group_uom" t-field="l.product_uom"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="text-right">
                                                        <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
                                                        <span t-field="l.discount"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="text-right">
                                                        <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.tax_id))"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="text-right">
                                                        <span t-field="l.price_subtotal"
                                                            t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "doc.pricelist_id.currency_id"}'/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </t>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>



        </template>
        <template id="report_custom">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
        <t t-call="sale.report_saleorder_document" t-lang="doc.partner_id.lang"/>
       </t>
      </t>
      </template>
      </data>
      </openerp>
```

Comment: After you make changes to the code, you have to restart the server and upgrade the module in the UI.I guess it is sales module in this case.

Comment: Yes I did all but still not working